# An other FPM instance listening on php5-fpm.sock

Tags: php, debian, php-fpm

i have set up multiple PHP versions in ISPconfig 3 and the hole thing actually works except i can not start more then one Version at a time then i get this error "An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock" i have been searching for hours but cant seem to find an answer to my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different socket then; running multiple instances bound to the same socket isn't possible.

---

By the way: Not just because of the policy of this site, but as well good for you: Try to work with your systems via cli / ssh / etc., and not with panels like `ISPConfig 3`. You will get much more knowledge and deeper insight doing so. Have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), which reads:

> If your question is not about [...] working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: I am sorry i have not read that! but anyway thanks for pointing that out and thanks for you help! :)